# Run each Virtual Machine as a separate application

Tags: virtualbox, icons, launcher, virtualization

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 with VirtualBox installed. I have a Windows 10 VM installed and a Kali VM as well. When they boot, they both come up as windows of the VirtualBox program, like so:

[image: Screenshot of icon]

But I would like it to look like Windows and Kali are separate "apps" installed on the system. So when each one is open, they will have their own icon in the launcher, with the Windows and Kali logo respectively.

I have tried this by making 2 .desktop files and dragging them to the launcher and then clicking on them, but that just opens the VM under a separate VirtualBox icon, just as is shown on the screenshot above.

Comment: Look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/83434/add-virtualbox-shortcut-in-unity-launcher-to-boot-to-a-vm - you can link to any icon in the .desktop file (use full paths there).

Answer (score 1):

OK, Thanks to Takkat, I've realised that if I change the Exec value in my desktop file, it would work perfectly.

Here is my old Exec entry:

```
Exec=VBoxManage startvm Windows
```

Here is the new one:

```
Exec=VirtualBox --startvm Windows
```

Not quite sure what the technical difference is, but hey, it works!